# What does it mean for an electron spin to have a local phase?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

I understand how a polarised wave can have a local phase, in that the horizontally polarised portion of the wave may not oscillate in the same phase as the vertically polarised portion, but how does an electron qubit have a local phase, considering it spins either clockwise or anticlockwise, or in some orientation in between, but the clockwise can't be out of phase with the anticlockwise can it? I mean what would that even mean?

Answer (score 1):

The wave you are referring to is not a real wave in the sense you imagine. It refers to the state vector in quantum mechanics. This vector lives in an abstract space (the famous Hilbert space), not physical space. If you multiply this vector by a complex number of modulus one, then this vector rotates  in the hilbert space. This vector  has information about the probability of some measurements. This vector can rotate in many ways in Hilbert space as the system evolves. In particular, if the only change in hilbert space results in the vector being multiplied by a complex number of modulus one, then we say the vector has changed its phase. The phase angle is the angle that you usually define in the plane of the complex numbers when you make a rotation.